# Missing measurements in nonlinear chemical processes

Tags: missing-data, rms

I am using an imputation method to handle missing measurements;TSR.The prediction model used is LW-PLS. Based on the my results, the RMSE increases when the percentage of missing measurements increases (from 5% to 40%). However, at 30% missing measurements, the RMSE decreases. Can i know why?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Why do you think the RMSE increases/decreases as a function of missingness? Did you use some sort of imputation method? If possible, please edit your question and give a minimal example of the results you obtained and a description how you obtained them.